# Can I provide the .NET Core DependencyInjection with a "resolver" to return a Moq of any service which isn't registered?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, moq

Given a class with a dependency:

```
class SomeService : ISomeService { ctor(ISomeDependency someDependency ... }
```

Using Moq I can mock out the dependency like this:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection()
.AddTransient(_ => Mock.Of<ISomeDependency>())
.AddTransient<ISomeService,SomeService>()
.BuildServiceProvider();

services.GetRequiredService<ISomeService>();
```

Is there anyway I can register a "provider" which the ServiceProvider will use if an implementation isn't registered? I'd like the ServiceProvider to return a `Mock.Of<T>` if the dependency `T` hasn't been registered.

I want to do this because I have some classes lots of dependencies and want to avoid some typing.

Comment: I deleted my original answer since it's wrong, and I'm leaving this as a comment since I haven't tried it out but it may point you in the right direction: All that `BuildServiceProvider()` does is construct a new `ServiceProvider`. You should be able to wrap it with your own implementation of `IServiceProvider` that has an implementation of `GetService` that handles the return value of `innerProvider.GetService` as appropriate (detect null and construct a mock instead).

Comment: @nlawalker I like the idea, but this only helps the consumer of the decorator - it doesn't change the resolution inside the service provider itself.

Comment: ServiceA depends on ServiceB. I register ServiceA, I do not register ServiceB. Implementing your suggestion works if the App asks for ServiceB - it detects null and returns the Mock, as you describe. But I want ServiceA. So your wrapper calls innerProvider for ServiceA, innerProvider attempts to construct A, and asks "itself" for B. There is no way to make the innerProvider ask the outer provider.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, I had already deleted my comment - was in the wrong frame of mind and my response did not make sense.

Comment: No problem, thank you nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can register a "provider" which the ServiceProvider will use if an implementation isn't registered?

With Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (MS.DI) there isn't a way to do this. What you’re looking for is *unregistered type resolution*. Most mature DI Containers actually contain hooks that allow to intercept calls from the library when an unregistered type is requested. But MS.DI, however, does not have such a feature. All registrations must be made explicitly and there is no way around it.